# How to calculate what gas price to use for transactions on RSK?

Tags: ethereum, rpc, web3js, rsk

I need to know how to set a proper gas price for my transactions on RSK network. I am familiar with the `eth_gasPrice` approach from Ethereum:

```sh
$ curl https://public-node.testnet.rsk.co -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_gasPrice","params":[],"id":1}'
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1,"result":"0x3938700"}
```

Is the above recommended for RSK as well?

Comment: I am a developer who uses Truffle framework to publish smart contracts on RSK. I also need to know the gas price and use it in my projects. In the RSK Truffle boxes they have a interesting approach to query and use the gas price.
It is using the query mentioned above, saving in a file and reading it in truffle-config file. I recommended it for developers:
https://developers.rsk.co/tutorials/truffle-boxes/rsk-starter-box/

Answer (score 9):

You have several ways to calculate the gas price.

From an **end user** point of view, you can get the gas price from:

- [RSK Stats](https://stats.rsk.co/)
- Metamask/Nifty/MEW proposed `gasPrice`  value when preparing a transaction

From a **developer** point of view, you need to know that RSK has a `minimumGasPrice` limit, this means that if you set a `gasPrice` below that minimum, your transaction will be rejected.

How to get `gasPrice`:

Using JSON-RPC method `eth_gasPrice`. This gives you a current average gas price in the network. It's a good idea to specify an additional 5% gas price as a buffer, in order to be above the average gas price.

The example code above you have is correct:

```sh
$ curl https://public-node.testnet.rsk.co -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_gasPrice","params":[],"id":1}'
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1,"result":"0x3938700"}
```

... however, do the following as well to calculate the amount with buffer:

```js
$ node -e "console.log(0x3938700 / 20 * 21);"
63000000
```

`eth_gasPrice` returns 60 million, but we use 63 million when submitting transactions.
For those familiar with Ethereum development, this is the **same** method as you would use there.

How to get `minimumGasPrice`:

Using JSON-RPC method `eth_getBlockByNumber` with best block number as parameter and getting `minimumGasPrice` from the response. As the minimum gas price [may change 1% between blocks, see RSKIP-09](https://github.com/rsksmart/RSKIPs/blob/master/IPs/RSKIP09.md), it is recommended to specify an additional 10% gas price as buffer, to ensure a 10 block window of valid `gasPrice`. This caters to a pessimistic scenario.

Example code to perform the above:

```sh
curl https://public-node.testnet.rsk.co -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_getBlockByNumber","params":["latest",false],"id":1}'
```

```json
{
   "jsonrpc" : "2.0",
   "result" : {
      "cumulativeDifficulty" : "0x2b7cd0b2",
      "size" : "0xbcc",
      "uncles" : [],
      "gasUsed" : "0x546fe",
      "hash" : "0x68abc09397ec6ae77acf52c195638dd9f93e5756eb1856c81e8e30cbbeef6b39",
      "difficulty" : "0x2b7cd0b2",
      "miner" : "0x1fab9a0e24ffc209b01faa5a61ad4366982d0b7f",
      "bitcoinMergedMiningMerkleProof" : "0x8bfb89a6e8a8fa0fee018e9dd0d86c0aea40806d3e8fe45e9454a250b763d978c812164690d7af62b31743db9944cc5ac6038d210ef6d1e4fb08c712f9a318c0538845ed4d3f3b61879aba5e79c58bc754213a9872f54c2da44051b3c0e04d4be382b6f1303386afc08c991a85aae39fa3263cbcbd9d4a05d8a2d0797204902de56af20198ad4a3b2c553e0c2500da50a536fd10233204c5a9837802f6816f740a146e58ebae0d7be3ca3a79f7d2a942e5ade058baa53e252162fefc136f33434e84753446aad913ea4baafd6bcaa145d37b9b3b85fec42d7bf47d5efef8e000",
      "paidFees" : "0x1395b92f0000",
      "stateRoot" : "0xb7fc903f8f60a3e0d0d80ea58348e9637e3a9a4c8f9de6e089326c9bfbb698ed",
      "transactions" : [ "<< redacted for brevity >>" ],
      "totalDifficulty" : "0x2eff7f12ec2c2655d",
      "bitcoinMergedMiningHeader" : "0x00000020901806378d89a22c6aaa772bab42ec41dfdb4dce77d361181600000000000000a0782738fa6b7ef70644de0aca393597462d9fb97d59c92680eba5e5a2b66af14c6efe5f5c75161904657655",
      "receiptsRoot" : "0xc930346e224a837fc426b900c07d3f744f4c82ac789d05624dbbe4e008dc2f22",
      "hashForMergedMining" : "0xb58502263dd8363d0c88287eb3436c731ff5763e5ed4d4919306b028001738f9",
      "transactionsRoot" : "0x9cc25cf985416ef18fa171f59b9d03f6921bad3c93f956dc0d472f9429b81167",
      "gasLimit" : "0x67c280",
      "bitcoinMergedMiningCoinbaseTransaction" : "0x00000000000000801d9be7d007fe4505303282a8fdd52df91d1292256a776a2181521c4513ee6c246088ac0000000000000000266a24aa21a9edee78f53b94245e73c99fb98a96b539836fa82b85a20de1c0d7984f0eabd198f600000000000000002a6a52534b424c4f434b3ab58502263dd8363d0c88287eb3436c731ff5763e5ed4d4919306b028001738f900000000",
      "logsBloom" : "0x00000000000000000000001000000008000000000040000000000000000000000000400000050000000400000000000400000000010000000000000000000000000000000080000000000004000000000000000000000080000000004000000000000000800000000000001000000000000000000000000002000008080000000000000000000000000001000208000000000000040000000000000420080000000000020008100000000000020010000080000000000082001000000000000000000001040000000000000000080000000030000001000880200004100200000000000020000000002000000000100000000000000000010200000000000000",
      "minimumGasPrice" : "0x387ee40",
      "timestamp" : "0x5ffe6e40",
      "number" : "0x1738f9",
      "parentHash" : "0x1276aa271525f757166acf767cd6100a25d0cba18f6caf925299276f3d439404",
      "sha3Uncles" : "0x1dcc4de8dec75d7aab85b567b6ccd41ad312451b948a7413f0a142fd40d49347",
      "extraData" : "0xd1018f504150595255532d62643739313837"
   },
   "id" : 1
}
```

The response for this is pretty large (see above), however, it does contain the info we need: `"minimumGasPrice" : "0x387ee40",`. The final step to include the buffer:

```js
$ node -e "console.log(0x387ee40 / 10 * 11);"
65164000
```

`eth_getBlockByNumber.minimumgasPrice` returns approximately 59 million, but we use approximately 65 million when submitting transactions.

For those familiar with Ethereum development, this is approach is different and only available on RSK.