# How to get the minimum gas price on RSK with web3.js?

Tags: rpc, web3js, rsk

I'm using web3.js to get the minimum gas price, but the following is not working:

```js
web3.eth.getBlock('latest').minimumGasPrice
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 9):

You can do this using web3.js like so:

```js
const block = await web3.eth.getBlock('latest');
const minimumGasPrice = block.minimumGasPrice;
```

Note that `getBlock()` involves a network request,
and therefore needs an `await`.

Your question only asked for a way to do this in Javascript,
but if you want to do the equivalent using **terminal commands**,
in case you have not done so yet,
check out the answer on this similar question:
[How to calculate what gas price to use for transactions on RSK?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65702552/194982)

Note: If you're coming from Ethereum development,
the `minimumGasPrice` field in this RPC response is RSK-only -
do not expect the same from Ethereum.