# How can I configure Hardhat to connect to RSK Testnet?

Tags: rsk, rootstock

To connect to an Ethereum Testnet,
the configuration in `hardhat.config.js` is like this:

```js
  networks: {
    ropsten: {
      url: `https://eth-ropsten.alchemyapi.io/v2/${ALCHEMY_API_KEY}`,
      accounts: [`${ROPSTEN_PRIVATE_KEY}`]
    }
  }
```

(taken from here: https://hardhat.org/tutorial/deploying-to-a-live-network.html )

How can I add a network config for the RSK Testnet?

(Note that I'm using a seed phrase instead of a raw private key)

Answer (score 7):

The network config in `hardhat.config.js` could be defined like so:

```js
  networks: {
    rsktestnet: {
      chainId: 31,
      url: 'https://public-node.testnet.rsk.co/',
      gasPrice: Math.floor(minimumGasPriceTestnet * TESTNET_GAS_MULT),
      gasMultiplier: TESTNET_GAS_MULT,
      accounts: {
        mnemonic: mnemonic,
        initialIndex: 0,
        // if using RSK dPath
        // Ref: https://developers.rsk.co/rsk/architecture/account-based/#derivation-path-info
        path: "m/44'/37310'/0'/0",
        // if using Ethereum dPath (e.g. for Metamask compatibility)
        // path: "m/44'/60'/0'/0",
        count: 10,
      },
    },
  },
```

Where

- `mnemonic` is your BIP-39 seed phrase.
- `TESTNET_GAS_MULT` set to any value more than or equal to `1`
- `minimumGasPriceTestnet` see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66999114/194982) or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65702552/194982)